# How to know whether a printer is shared on CLI shell?

Tags: command-line, fedora, cups

How can I tell if a printer is shared on the command line instead of CUPS web GUI shell (e.g., http://localhost:631/printers/HP_LaserJet_Professional_P1108).

Comment: `lpstat -s` or `cat /etc/cups/printers.conf`

Comment: Thank you @Jesse_b. `cat /etc/cups/printers.conf` is what I need. If you could add an answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information in the `/etc/cups/printers.conf` file.

Use:

```
view /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

or

```
less /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

Comment: I found that cups service should be restarted before `less /etc/cups/printers.conf`